# Sort a multidimensional array in PHP by a given value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have the following structure:

```
{
"data": {
    "array_1": [
        {
            "name": "Robert Kalani"
        },
        {
            "name": "Balkan Boy",
        }
    ],
    "array_2": [
        {
            "name": "Pepe Dolan"
        },
        {
            "name": "John Nolan",
        }
    ],
    "array_3": [
        {
            "name": "Phillip A. Luna",
        },
        {
            "name": "Eugene Garcia"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I would like to sort each array by the name key in alpabetical order, not sure on how to do that, I've read about **array_multisort** but it seemed not to work. Would greatly appreciate some help

Here is the expected output

```
{
"data": {
    "array_1": [
        {
            "name": "Balkan Boy",
        },
        {
            "name": "Robert Kalani"
        }
    ],
    "array_2": [
        {
            "name": "John Nolan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pepe Dolan"
        }
    ],
    "array_3": [
        {
            "name": "Eugene Garcia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Phillip A. Luna"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: could you please show us your expected output array structure?

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas just added it now, thank you :)

Comment: is your data in JSON structure?

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas yes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your JSON Data
  $data = '{
"data": {
  "array_1": [{ "name": "Robert Kalani" }, { "name": "Balkan Boy" }],
  "array_2": [{ "name": "Pepe Dolan" }, { "name": "John Nolan" }],
  "array_3": [{ "name": "Phillip A. Luna" }, { "name": "Eugene Garcia" }]
}
}
';

  $result = [];

  // Convert your JSON data to associative array
  $array = json_decode($data, true)['data'];


  function sort_by_name($a, $b)
  {
    return $a > $b;
  }

  foreach ($array as $item) {
    uasort($item, "sort_by_name");
    $result[] = $item;
  }


  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Balkan Boy
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Robert Kalani
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John Nolan
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Pepe Dolan
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Eugene Garcia
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Phillip A. Luna
                )

        )

)
```